# What is the shir shel yom for Rosh Hodesh Tevet according to the tradition of the GR"A?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, rosh-chodesh-new-month, vilna-gaon, shir-shel-yom

My understanding of the tradition of the Vilna Gaon (whose tradition is followed in Israel) with respect to *shir shel yom* is that every day has *exactly* one *shir shel yom*. For example, during *Hanukkah*, the *shir* is [Psalm 30](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2630.htm) and on *Rosh Hodesh* it's [Psalm 104](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a4.htm) *instead of* the regular *shir shel yom*.

So my question is on *Rosh Hodesh Tevet* (which is also *Hanukkah*), what is the *shir* according to this tradition?

Comment: similar question... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/not-saying-shir-shel-yom-on-rosh-chodesh?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The popular *sidur* "תפלת כל פה" has a list of all the red-letter days' daily psalms. It says that 104 is said on *rosh chodesh Teves* (and also on *Shabas rosh chodesh*, by the way).

Comment: Does this Siddur claim to follow the traditions of the Vilna Gaon in this matter? Does it, for instance, mention that 30 is _not_ recited on R"Ch Tevet?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it does indicate that 30 is not said on _rosh chodesh Teves_. I don't recall whether it claims to follow the tradition of the _gaon_ (and don't have it at hand. I'll try to remember to check).

Answer (score 7):

[Maaseh Rav 157](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33900&st=&pgnum=35) (a work documenting the practices of the Vilna Gaon) records the answer according to the tradition you ask about:

> אין אומרים שיר של יום של יומו ואומרים במקומו בב' ימים דר"ח ברכי נפשי (מזמור ק"ד) שהוא שיר של ר"ח ודוחה אפי' של שבת ופשיטא של חנוכה
>   [On Rosh Chodesh] the Song of the Day for that day [of the week] is not said, and in its place is said on both days of Rosh Chodesh "Barkhi Nafshi" (Psalm 104), for it is the song of Rosh Chodesh. And it even pushes off [the song] of Shabbat, and obviously [that] of Chanukkah. (my translation)

Comment: Why is it obvious? It seems inconsistent with the preference for Maftir/Haftorah.

Comment: @Yishai I am not the Gra to answer for him, but I can note that relegating Chanukkah to Maftir instead of Shvii (on Shabbat/R"Ch) is probably indicative of the superiority of R"Ch that it gets a real Aliyah (and 3 Aliyot on a weekday). (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66181/759 is counter to that a little bit)