# Shabbos Chanuka - Rosh Chodesh - Torah reading mistake

Tags: chanuka, mistakes, rosh-chodesh-new-month, haftarah, maftir

[Orach Chaim 684:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=296) says that on Shabbos Chanuka that is also Rosh Chodesh we take out three Sifrei Torah. In the first one we give six Aliyos in the Parsha of the week. In the second one we read about Rosh Chodesh. In the third one we read the special Chanuka reading. Afterwards we say the Haftora of Chanuka.

If in error the Shul read the Chanuka reading in the second Torah, and finished the reading of Rosh Chodesh in the third Torah, do they then say the Rosh Chodesh Haftora as they finalized with a Rosh Chodesh reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the *Beur Halacha* commentary on the same page in your link. He explicitly states that even if you make a mistake as the one you listed, the Haftarah is still the Chanukah haftarah. The reason is because of *Pirsumei Nisa* (proclaiming the miracle of Chanukah.)

He states that even if you accidentally recited the Rosh Hodesh haftarah in error, it's fine.